# Verify hmac in deno?

Tags: hmac, deno

I'm converting some things from node to deno and I noticed that I can't use the existing hmac verification I'm using in node. I'm verifying hmac from a shopify webhook, and in node, I'm doing it as such:

```
import crypto from "crypto";
    const body = request.rawBody; // fastify 
    const hash = crypto
        .createHmac("sha256", secretKey)
        .update(body)
        .digest("base64");

        return hash === hmac
```

How would I achieve the same in deno?